# Descent Direction in Taylor's series

Tags: optimization, taylor-expansion, gradient-descent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwkJN.jpg)

Can anyone help me with the proof. I do not understand how that norm(d) term is appearing in the Taylor's series.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: In a way, this factor is immaterial because it can be absorbed in the function $\alpha$.

Comment: @Jose Thank you for your suggestion. I am a new user in this forum.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you for your reply. I understand that but can you make me understand how that extra term after the gradient term is coming into picture? How that norm term is appearing in the Taylor series expansion for this particular equation?